# Make a button that plays a video which at the bottom of the video has 4 more buttons and the 4 buttons play different videos

Tags: javascript, html, css

MAKE A BUTTON THAT PLAYS A VIDEO AND THE VIDEO HAS 4 BUTTON BELOW IT

I tried searching it up here but all I found was how to make a button that plays a Youtube video. I wanted it in fullscreen and also buttons that play another video.

Comment: YouTube includes an API to change the video easily through event listeners. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add a video with controls, you can use the [HTML5 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag to add a video, and add the controls attribute to enable the controls.

Comment: can u paste the code. also if you click the button everything on the screen disappears and the only thing left is the video IN FULLSCREEN/FULL SIZE.